# Prevent Rider from generating namespaces around new scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rider

I'm trying out Rider for Unity development. When I create a new script in the Scripts folder, it always wraps the class in

```cs
namespace DefaultNamespace {

    class MyClass //...

}
```

This is super annoying. I don't want a namespace assigned to every script, forcing them to be indented and for my other scripts having to have more `using` imports.

I can't figure out how to disable this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the top of rider click

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code style -> C# -> After file-scoped namespace directive
[image]

Set file-scoped namespace to 1

Set inside namespace to 0

UPDATE:

Answer above resolve another issue, it`s about formatting existing code.
To resolve this question you need to change template inside Rider settings, which you can do next way:

Settings -> Editor -> File Templates -> C# -> class
[image]
There you can setup everything you need and remove what you don`t need